# SDK iOS - Unable to build when updating to 8.0.5 or 8.0.6

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

We have configured SFMCSdk on iOS for our project using Cocoapods to install version 8.0.4, and it worked fine.

But considering we now have random crashes with the SDK, we wanted to update to 8.0.6 but we have compilation errors :

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/SFMCSDK.h"

.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk/SFMCSDK.framework/Headers/SFMCSDK.h:27:1: error: umbrella header for module 'SFMCSDK' does not include header 'SFKeyStoreManager.h'

<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/SFMCSDK.h"

.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk/SFMCSDK.framework/Headers/SFMCSDK.h:27:1: error: umbrella header for module 'SFMCSDK' does not include header 'SFEncryptionKey.h'

<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'SFMCSDK'
```

Do we need to do something to update from 8.0.4 to 8.0.6? Did we miss something in the doc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some back and forth, we have been able to identify the problem : in our Build Settings, we had set the flags `Treat Warnings as Errors` to `Yes`, which caused the "Umbrella Header" warning to be treated as an error and failed to compile.

To "fix" this, we disabled this flag only for the "Umbrella Header" by adding  `-Wno-incomplete-umbrella` to the `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` in Build Settings. This way, we can still use `Treat Warnings as Errors` while ignoring the "Umbrella Header" warning.

The correct fix, however, would be on SalesForce's side to fix the problematic header import in `SFMCSdk.h`.

Hope it helps!